# Deleted gem 'webpack' but keeps giving error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, rubygems

I have installed `gem 'webpacker'` and then, commited to the server. However, when I deleted the gem, the new setting haven't been updated on Heroku.

When I run the app:

**/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method`webpacker' for # (NoMethodError)**

Someone knows how to re-do gem process in the server? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely you still have some config items leftover. Search your application for `webpack` and `webpacker`. You may find a webpack folder in your config, at least.

https://github.com/rails/webpacker

I would recommend going through the setup again, to make sure you removed everything.

Comment: Thats exactly the problem. Thanks! I went throught every step to check any webpack files were stored, and deleted them, manually. As I'm using Rubymine I could check each error, to what files there were pointing. I guess it would be a little challenging for people who's starting and dont use IDE. (But my advise for who have same problem: go ahead and delete every webpack files)

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems that your Gemfile.lock is not being updated.

First delete the Gemfile.lock on local system 
Then remove the gem from Gemfile on local system.
Then bundle on local system with the gem in Gemfile removed.

Commit and Push to Heroku.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I tried this method, but it still shows the error. Maybe is an issue with the webpacker.